# NetBeans: Specifying html for Applet which uses JSObject for debugging

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, applet

I would like to specify html for my applet and debug it in NetBeans.

The helpful is following:
My applet class is `MainApplet`.
I put `MainClass.html` in the same folder with `MainApplet.java`.
After this I run applet via right click on file in NetBeans and selecting Debug "MainApplet.java".
It looks like applet tag from `MainApplet.html` is used, e.g. dimensions of applet are taken from my `MainApplet.html`.

BUT:

When `netscape.javascript.JSObject.getWindow(this)` is called in applet `netscape.javascript.JSException` is thrown. This is when running applet in applet viewer.
In browser all works good - no exception thrown.

**Is it possible to debug applet by right click on it in NetBeans and select Debug and at the same time `JSObject.getWindow(this)` is executed successfully?
What should be configured to obtain such behaviour?**

I use NetBeans 6.5

If there are completely different scenarios which result in easy debug it would be good to know about them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging an applet uses appletviewer, not a true browser. You can however, debug an applet running in a browser. Here's the explanation of how it's done: [Debugging Applet Remotely](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingAppletRemotely)

Comment: This works! Thanks.
Not exactly what I need but anyway very useful!